# R code runs when required parameter is not specified

Tags: r, for-loop

I am assisting a colleague with adding functionality to one of his R packages.

I have implemented nonparametric bootstrapping using a `for` loop construct in R.

```
# perform resampling
# resample `subsample_size` values with or without replacement   replicate_size times
for (i in 1:replicate_size) {
   if (replacement == TRUE) { # bootstrapping
       z <- sample(x, size = subsample_size, replace = TRUE)
      zz <- sample(x, size = subsample_size, replace = TRUE)
      } else { # subsampling
        z <- sample(x, size = subsample_size, replace = FALSE)
        zz <- sample(x, size = subsample_size, replace = FALSE)
   }
    # calculate statistic
    boot_samples[i] <- min(zz) - max(z)
}
```

The above loop is nested within another `for` loop, which itself is nested within a function (details not shown). The code I'm dealing with is messy, and there are most certainly more efficient ways of coding things up, but I've had to leave it be since my colleague is only familiar with very basic and rudimentary coding constructs.

Upon running said function, I specified all required arguments (`replicate_size`, `replacement`) except `subsample_size`. `subsample_size` is needed to carry out the resampling. This mistake on my part was revealing because, for some strange reason, the code still runs without throwing an error regarding missing a value for `subsample_size`.

**Question**: Does anyone have any idea on why this happens?

I'd include more code, but it is very verbose and unwieldy (his code, not mine). Running the `for` loop outside the function does indeed raise the error regarding the missing value as expected.

Comment: Is there an object called `subsample_size` in your global environment?

Comment: @AdamQuek Yes, but only when I run the `for' loop outside the function and explicitly specify all required arguments.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/sample): For sample the default for size is the number of items inferred from the first argument, so that sample(x) generates a random permutation of the elements of x (or 1:x).

Comment: case in point, for `test <- function(x, sample_size) sample(x, size=sample_size, replace=TRUE)`, the call `test(1:12)` will provide the same sample call as `sample(1:12, replace=TRUE)`.

Comment: @AdamQuek Thanks. That's clear.  I should have mentioned that I used `x` simply  as a placeholder. I'm acutually resampling values from a pairwise distance matrix. I'd add this detail to my post.

Comment: Quick fix would be to set default `subsample_size` as NULL to error out.

Comment: @AdamQuek Ah! Because all other arguments in the function have set defaults except `subsample_size`. I'll try setting `subsample_size = NULL`. Still I wonder when R is pulling the outputted bootstrapped values from...

Comment: Anyway, things are working as expected now.